# Gnome Screensaver not blanking screen completely

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, screensaver

Curious, sometimes after several days the gnome screensaver doesn't turn off the backlight. It used to always work. Logging out fixes it for a few days, but then it appears again. Any ideas? I've removed and reinstalled the gnome-screensaver, even created a new user, same issue.

It actually clears the screen, desktop not visible, just a slight illumination of the screen.

also sometimes when resuming from a locked session, the screensaver kicks in almost immediately after unlocking, with no user input. Its set at 15 min but sometimes, like I said happens right away. A log out fixes this as well - for a while

Today after resuming from the screensaver, the desktop did not come back. The backlight was illuminated but nothing else. Had to CTRL+ALT+F3 and do a reboot as the GUI was not working. I decided to do a complete shutdown/restart rather than a reboot. If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: seems like a complete shutdown rather than rebooting has fixed the issue

Comment: spoke too soon. Still happening, this time after 3 days or so.